# if Statement Acting Up

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

This is within the Update function. Excuse the `brakeTorque` stuff, that's just a bandaid for now. This is a drag racing game, and Staged means ready to go. Once both cars are staged, and the race hasn't started yet, then there should be a delay of 5 seconds then the words "GO 1" should appear (I added `stupidCounter` as a debugging tool). Then it sets the start time. Then it sets Racing to true in order to keep it from jumping back into this `if` statement again.

The issue is that it keeps jumping back in the `if` statement every frame; printing: `GO1 GO2 GO3` etc.

The word "GO" is not mentioned anywhere else in any other script.
The "Racing" boolean is not mentioned anywhere else in any script.

Here's my code:

```
if(Staged && OtherCarStaged() && !Racing)
{
    RearRightWheel.brakeTorque = 10000;
    RearLeftWheel.brakeTorque = 10000;
    FrontRightWheel.brakeTorque = 10000;
    FrontLeftWheel.brakeTorque = 10000;
    yield WaitForSeconds(5);
    stupidCounter += 1;
    Debug.Log("GO " + stupidCounter);
    mainTimerStart = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
    Racing = true;
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's a scope issue with the `Racing` variable

Comment: I tried changing it to a private bool. no dice

Comment: WAIIIIT. if it was jumping back into the if it would be waiting for 5 seconds each time. but its not

Comment: It has something to do with the WaitforSeconds, i commented it out and it didnt keep counting GO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your function is a coroutine. The issue in your code is probably because you are calling the coroutine in every update frame. You either need to add a check to call the coroutine only once, or use your own timer to handle this instead of a coroutine.

Based on your mentioned requirement I think your code should go like this

```
var timeLeft : float = 5;
function Update()
{
    StartCountdown();
}

function StartCountdown()
{
    if(Staged && OtherCarStaged() && !Racing)
    {
         // your stuff
         timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
         if(timeLeft <= 0)
         { 
             Debug.Log("GO");
             mainTimerStart = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
             Racing = true;
         }
    }
}
```

Or, if you want to go with Coroutines, it would go like this

```
function Update()
{
    if(!countdownStarted && Staged && OtherCarStaged())
        StartCoroutine(StartCountdown(5));
}

var countdownStarted : bool = false;
function StartCountdown(float time)
{
    countdownStarted = true;
    yield WaitForSeconds(time);

    Debug.Log("GO ");
    mainTimerStart = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
    Racing = true;
}
```

Comment: Splendid answer! perfect

Comment: @TroyStafford Glad to help!